# Why are 32-bit values exported from OCX as 64 bits?

Tags: c++, 32bit-64bit, ocx

We have a 32-bit C++ OCX that exports a property:

`LPITEMIDLIST CMyClass::GetCurrentPIDL()`

In a 32-bit binary, `LPITEMIDLIST` of course is a 32-bit pointer.

The 32-bit C++ client app .uses `#import` to import the OCX. The generated .TLH file contains this:

```
__declspec(property(get=GetCurrentPIDL,put=PutCurrentPIDL))
__int64 CurrentPIDL;
```

The client can't access the property without a typecast because the compiler complains that it can't convert an `__int64` to an `LPITEMIDLIST`.

It all works, but still I'd like to know why the OCX exports the property as an `__int64` rather than an `LPITEMIDLIST`. It doesn't seem like I should have to cast it.

Am I doing something wrong in the OCX code, or is this just the way it is?

TIA

Comment: Raw pointers are not Automation compatible.  Your client also has zero odds using your OCX in a 64-bit process directly, you'll need to provide him with a 64-bit build.

Comment: Thanks. I should clarify, by "client" I was referring to the client app, i.e., the application that uses the OCX. The OCX was written by a third party, but both the OCX and the client app are ours. We build 32- and 64-bit versions of both.